# Where to place a frequently accessed file in an ASP.NET application?

Tags: asp.net

I am writing an ASP.NET Web Form application.

Each time a request arrives my aspx page, I will use an object to do some logic. This object is deserialized from a pre-made file.

There'll be many requests to my aspx page so I don't want to deserialize this object every time a request comes in. **Becuase as I remember, ASP.NET will serve different requests with different threads. And the one thread reading the file will block other threads from reading this file. So hurt the performance.** (But I am not sure about this, please correct me if I am wrong.)

The file will be updated weekly or bi-weekly. So I need to re-deserialize the corresponding object once the file is updated.

My questions are:

- Where should I put the code to deserialize the object from file?
- How to monitor the file change?

My current plan is:

- Deserialize the object from file at the Application_Start() event. And store this object in Cache.
- Use FileSystemWatcher to monitor the folder containing the file and update the object once file is modified.

Is this design OK? Is there any more reasonable design?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Store the file in the [App_Data](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ex526337(v=vs.100).aspx).

FileSystemWatcher is ok but I would suggest it to run as a windows service. You could have a page dedicated to refresh the cache (ex: www.webpage.com/refreshcache.aspx). You could also just setup a scheduler to refresh the cache every night.